# jQuery: "on" click event not working in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, click, jquery-events

**I know that this question is duplicate. I read other question and answers but cannot get any result.**

I have a dynamic table:

**HTML**

```
<table id="networklist" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>icon</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
          // forech is here
        <tr data-rowid="@dto.Id">
         // more td
            <td>
                <i id="delete" data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-trash" style="margin-left: 1em; cursor: pointer"></i>
                <i id="edit" data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

**JS**

```
$("#networklist").on("click","tr i #delete",function () {
  debugger;

 var id = $(this).data("id");

});
```

I try this and many other selectors but click event not worked.
how can I solve this issue?

Update: I don't have unique id in `delete` and `edit` i have it on `tr`.

Comment: Those ID's dont seem unique...

Comment: do you have same id more tan one-time (delete and edit)? if yes then it will not work

Comment: well you are saying i has a child that is delete.... and ids are supposed to be unique....

Comment: @AlivetoDie no, I update my question.

Comment: Does each `tr` have a `<i id="delete" . . . ` and a `<i id="edit" . . . ` in it?

Comment: @talemyn yes, is correct.

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh - that is your problem then (at least part of it).  ID's must be unique to a page.  Both JavaScript and jQuery will only recognize the first instance of an ID on a page . . . the rest will be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`id` need to be unique for each element. So go with `class` like below:-

***Demo example:-***

```js
$("#networklist").on("click","tr i.delete ,tr i.edit",function () {
 var id = $(this).data("id");
   console.log(id);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="networklist" class="table table-hover">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>name</th>
        <th>icon</th>
        <th>username</th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

        <tr data-rowid="@dto.Id">
            <td>ABC</td>
            <td>ICON</td>
            <td>ALIVE</td>
             <td>
                <i data-id="1" class="fa fa-trash delete" style="margin-left: 1em; cursor: pointer">del</i>
                <i data-id="2" class="fa fa-pencil edit" style="cursor: pointer">edit</i>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr data-rowid="@dto.Id">
            <td>DEF</td>
            <td>ICON</td>
            <td>DIE</td>
             <td>
                <i data-id="3" class="fa fa-trash delete" style="margin-left: 1em; cursor: pointer">del</i>
                <i data-id="4" class="fa fa-pencil edit" style="cursor: pointer">edit</i>
            </td>
        </tr>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to change this line:

```
$("#networklist").on("click","tr #delete",function () {
```

Because your selector is wrong. there is no element with id `#delete` in `i` tag.
And you should use class `.delete` instead of id because id should be unique within the document

Comment: and when there are multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: @epascarello  `tr` is multiple and in foreach.

Comment: @epascarello use class `delete` instead of id. your ids should be unique

Comment: @SoheilAlizadeh And there are multiple ids with delete...

Answer (score 0):

You need to target `tr i#delete` not `tr i #delete`. Currently you are targeting children of `i` tags, whereas you need to target `i` tags with the `id` property value of "delete".

```js
$("#networklist").on("click", "tr i#delete", function() {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table id="networklist" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>icon</th>
      <th>username</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

    <tr data-rowid="@dto.Id">
      <td>Chris</td>
      <td>My icon</td>
      <td>Tumbleweed</td>
      <td>
        <i id="delete" data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-trash" style="margin-left: 1em; cursor: pointer"></i>
        <i id="edit" data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-pencil" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

However as others have pointed out, the use of the id attribute in your scenario is just all wrong. Perhaps you should revisit your code and change it to something like so:

```js
$("#networklist").on("click", ".delete", function() {
  alert('clicked!');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

<table id="networklist" class="table table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>name</th>
      <th>icon</th>
      <th>username</th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr data-rowid="@dto.Id">
      <td>Chris</td>
      <td>My icon</td>
      <td>Tumbleweed</td>
      <td>
        <i data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-trash delete" style="margin-left: 1em; cursor: pointer"></i>
        <i data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-pencil edit" style="cursor: pointer"></i>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your selector is looking for

```
<tr><td><i><x id="delete"></i></td></tr>
```

The space in the selector is looking for a child of the `i` not the `i` iteself. Also ids have to be unique so you can not use the same id mutliple times so make it a class name.

```
<i data-id="@dto.Id" class="fa fa-trash delete" ...>
```

and change the selector

```
$("#networklist").on("click","tr i.delete",function () {
  var id = $(this).data("id");
});
```